# Fail to prrint out the error message in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have following circular convolution implemented. I would like to restrict the length of first input must be no longer than the second input. If inputs violate the rule, I would like to print an error message.

```
roll :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
roll _ [] = []
roll [] _ = []
roll h x = sample : roll h (tail x) 
     where sample = sum $ zipWith (*) h x 

circConv :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
circConv h x
         | lenx >= lenh = take lenx $ roll (reverse h) $ drop (lenx - lenh `div` 2) $ cycle x
         | otherwise  = error "length of first input should be no great than that of the second one"
           where lenx = length x
                 lenh = length h
```

After I run it, I got following output from GHCi

```
ghci> circConv [1,2,3,4,5,6] [1 1]

<interactive>:61:1:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `circConv'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: circConv [1, 2, 3, 4, ....] [1 1]
    In an equation for `it': it = circConv [1, 2, 3, ....] [1 1]

<interactive>:61:25:
    No instance for (Num (a1 -> a0)) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a1 -> a0))
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: 1 1
    In the second argument of `circConv', namely `[1 1]'

<interactive>:61:27:
    No instance for (Num a1) arising from the literal `1'
    The type variable `a1' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the first argument of `1', namely `1'
    In the expression: 1 1
    In the second argument of `circConv', namely `[1 1]'
```

PS: I know there are other way to deal with exceptions/errors in Haskell. As a beginner, I am not there yet.

Thanks

Comment: You need to put a comma in your second list: `[1,1]`, not `[1 1]`.

Comment: If you correct `[1 1]` to `[1,1]`, the result will be `length of the first input should not be greater than the second`

Comment: @BoldizsárNémeth that's what he wants to happen.

Comment: Others have explained what your error was, but the reason your `error` message isn't printed is that that can only happen if GHCi gets to the runtime stage, after compilation has already succeeded. Here compilation itself errs out at the type checking stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As spotted by jwodder, the problem is in the second argument to circConv. I'll try to explain the problem, as well as how to read the compiler error message.

```
ghci> circConv [1,2,3,4,5,6] [1 1]
               problem is here ^
```

Basically, GHC interprets that as `1` applied to the function `1`. This makes no sense, and so the compiler spits the dummy a bit.

You may notice the last error message contains these lines. GHC helpfully points out where the error is.

```
In the first argument of `1', namely `1'
In the expression: 1 1
In the second argument of `circConv', namely `[1 1]'
```

Here GHC is telling you that it's using `1` as an argument to `1` and using the whole thing as the second argument to `circConv`.

The next problem arises due to the language defining numeric literals to be polymorphic. What this means is that when you ask GHC the type of `1`, it will tell you `1 :: Num a => a`. What this says is that the literal `1` is a value for any type a where a is part of the Num class. Usually monomorphism restriction will shield you from this little detail, but it's helpful to know. This gives rise to the next error on the stack.

```
No instance for (Num (a1 -> a0)) arising from the literal `1'
```

What this says is that you've provided a literal number `Num a => a` but it's being treated as a function `(a1 -> a0)` because you're applying an argument to it. These two conflicting constraints manifest as a failure to find an instance for `Num` which is a function also.

Finally, this bubbles up to be the very last error.

```
No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `circConv'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

Because GHC failed to infer a type for the second argument of circConv, it cannot therefore infer a concrete type for the expression `circConv [1, 2, 3, ....] [1 1]`, and hence it cannot run it.

To fix this problem, simply change the last parameter to `[1,1]`.